# Magento 2 Professional Developer certification study guidelines

Tags: magento2, certification

I want to take to the exam of the Magento 2 Professional Developer Certification.

Before, I have read "swiftotter" website study guidelines online. This time "swiftotter" provide study guideline free but now they take fees of study guidelines.

Anyone have this study guideline? then please give me.

Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: DM if you need it on discounted price :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "swiftotter" site now not provides the free study guides.Please refer the following reference link for preparation.It is best.

https://github.com/magento-notes/magento2-exam-notes

Answer (score 3):

You can still take the practice test here: https://swiftotter.com/technical/certifications/magento-2-certified-developer-practice-test#/

The basic version is free, you can choose to pay for better / more questions.

As for a copy of the study guide - why do you not simply pay them for their work? They even refund you if you fail.

Comment: Please send me study guide if available

Comment: I don't have it. It's not free.

Comment: Before somemonths it is freely available

Comment: Yes and now they want to get paid for the work they put into it, which I think is completely ok. The study guide now will be better than the one from a few months ago, because they spent some time improving it.

Comment: Any other free study guidelines for this ?

Answer (score 0):

nothing is free in the magento 2 "community". Used to be the fundamentals of mage dev videos were free now theyre US700 swiftotter guides were free now theyre US70 access per month.
Now Adobe have bought Mage expect a subscription model which will increase by 50% every 9 or 10 months ad infinitum.
It's all got pretty greedy and grubby and looks to get worse.
Dan

Comment: This is nonsense. There are a ton of free plugins out there, for example on Github and packagist. There are also many free resources, for example blogs or tutorials on youtube (to name one: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRFDWo7jTlrpEsJxzc7WyPw). Not to mention the time ppl spend here to answer questions and help others understand Magento better.